# Google Map's API for BMTC (Bangalore Metropolitan Transport Corporation)

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working an Android App that displays bus route information when users inputs a route number.Is there any way i can fetch this information using google map's API??

Comment: Your question is very wide and not specific. If it is about google map's API read documentation, but if you have problem with your code, provide part of code and ask question about code (e.g. error found in code)

Answer (score 1):

As **@VolAnd** said, this question is very wide.

I found something that might help you if i understood you question correctly.

> When user inputs a bus route number, you want to fetch route details( bus stops and timings).

Well for this you can use http://www.mybmtc.com/ search api.

You can check this [link](https://github.com/openbangalore/bmtc/blob/master/scraper/getBusStops/getRoute.py#L50) to know how to use it, but its in Python language.

> ... i can fetch this information using google map's API?? ....

If you want to search bus routes and show it on google map, then you can use google maps api's Direction service [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes). You need to specify travelMode as **TRANSIT** and TransitMode as **BUS**. You can specify all in between stops as waypoint[] in [TransitOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#TransitOptions)

So  a quick answer,

1. Get and validate route number provided by user using mybmtc.com search.
2. That will give you details of all the stops on that route.
3. Use google maps Direction service to  locate routes between origin and destination of that route.

You have to work hard for this.
Let me know if anything is missing.